# Django remove loop using orm

Tags: django, python-3.x, orm

I am fetching data from url.And while inserting data i have to run query again and again.

Data from url

```
[{'Date': '22-Aug-2019', 'Open': 10905.3, 'High': 10908.25, 'Low': 10718.3, 'Close': 10741.35, 'Shares Traded': 668193449, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 18764.38},
{'Date': '23-Aug-2019', 'Open': 10699.6, 'High': 10862.55, 'Low': 10637.15, 'Close': 10829.35, 'Shares Traded': 667079625, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 20983.75}, {'Date': '26-Aug-2019', 'Open': 11000.3, 'High': 11070.3, 'Low': 10756.55, 'Close': 11057.85, 'Shares Traded': 684141923, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 22375.99}]
```

models.py

```
class BusinessShareInfo(models.Model) :
    Date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    Opens = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    High = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    Low = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    Close = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    Shares_Traded = models.IntegerField()
    Turnover = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
```

views.py
As you can see here date in json is comming like "Date: 22-Aug-2019" so i am converting it into YYYY-MM-DD format and than storing in database.

```
def insert_api_data(request):
    ''' Inserting data from api'''
    dataset = requests.get(config['url']['API_FETCH_URL']).json()
    for data in dataset :
        monthword = data['Date'][3:6]
        newWord = monthword[0].upper() + monthword[1:3].lower() 
        x = strptime(newWord,'%b').tm_mon
        l = data['Date']
        date = l[7:] + '-' + str(x) + '-' + l[:2]
        info = BusinessShareInfo.objects.create(Date = date,Opens=data['Open'],High=data['High'],Low=data['Low'],Close=data['Close'],Shares_Traded=data['Shares Traded'],Turnover=data['Turnover (Rs. Cr)'])
        info.save()
    return render(request,'BusinessShareInfo.html')
```

There are 1000s of records in  dataset fetched from json.I am looping for each and then inserting.How can i bulk insert with dateformant yyyy-mm-dd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are hitting database twice by calling `create()` and `save()` methods. You only need `create()` method here. Also there is an option to [**`bulk_create()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) objects. Here is an example:

```
info_set = []
for data in dataset :
    monthword = data['Date'][3:6]
    newWord = monthword[0].upper() + monthword[1:3].lower() 
    x = strptime(newWord,'%b').tm_mon
    l = data['Date']
    date = l[7:] + '-' + str(x) + '-' + l[:2]
    info_set.append(BusinessShareInfo(Date = date,Opens=data['Open'],High=data['High'],Low=data['Low'],Close=data['Close'],Shares_Traded=data['Shares Traded'],Turnover=data['Turnover (Rs. Cr)']))

BusinessShareInfo.objects.bulk_create(info_set)
```

Comment: ruddra sir can you please convert this to bulk_create().I will accept your answer

Comment: ruddra do i have to make any changes to model.

Comment: no, you do not have to. Also I have answered with bulk_create here.